# Sending value by "form", but Node.js doesn't store data in db

Tags: node.js, ajax, routes

I'm building simple online forum using Node.js and Ajax; however I can't get GET request.

What I want to do is to display all comments from database when index.html is loaded. it should request GET to Node.js and send back all data from database displaying on index.html.

Here is my Ajax (index.html)

```
  $(function(){

  var $username = $('#username');
  var $comments = $('#comments');
  var $result = $('#result');

    //For GET request
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/',
    dataType: 'json'
    success: function(orders){
      $.each(orders, function(i, order){
            $result.append('<li>Name: ' + order.username + '</li>');
            $result.append('<li>Comment: ' + order.comments + '</li>');
      });
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('error loading orders');
    }
  });
```

Here is my app.js

```
app.use('/', router);
```

Here is my route

```
router.get('/',function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("Confirmed GET");
    // Users.find({}).then(function(user){
    //   res.json(user);
    // }).catch(next);
});
```

Right now it displays nothing but index.html after loading the page. Is it impossible to send request to same page using ('/')?

Actually, I can see all data after typing "http://localhost:3000/users" if its request is to ('/users'), but not ('/').

Any ideas help me. Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest to put a console.log on the router (server side) as well on the client side, try to figure it out if each part is answering the call from another. I might give you a clue about what is happening.

Comment: After dataType: 'json', there was no comma, so I added. But if I write console.log inside Ajax, it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." in browser(console) . I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If I put console.log in server side, it printed out only before router GET.

Comment: So, it seems that you Ajax is not triggering the router. Why don't you use a different router for this event? It will not reload the page and will not mix with the get you receive from the page load?

Comment: Thank you Mauricio Noris Freire. It seemed that forgetting a comma after dataType was messing my codes around as well as my way of thinking of how the route works. I did "/users" as you told me, and it worked fine. Thank you very much.